# CloudFlare adds unnecessary HTTPS redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, cloudflare

I want all URLs to be served on the `www` subdomain and over HTTPS.

Simple Apache config:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
    RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L] 
</IfModule>
```

CloudFlare SSL is set to Full (strict) and there is a page rule defined as follows:

- Match: http://example.com/*
- Forward URL (301)
- Target: https://www.example.com/$1

This is what I'd want it to look like

- HTTP GET /
- 301 https://wwww.example.com

This is what actually happens:

- GET /
- 301 https://example.com
- 301 https://www.example.com

It is interesting to note that the HTTPS redirect is always first, unrelated to the Apache config.

Answer (score 0):

Looked in the wrong place. The CPanel the site was hosted on had a LetsEncrypt setting to "Enforce HTTPS", which forced the redirect. Disabled every kind of HTTPS redirect and left only the one in `.htaccess`, now works as it should.